# Azure Log Analytics - KQL - query for getting year-to-date count

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

I want to write a query in Azure Log Analytics to get month-to-date and year-to-date data for number of VMs. I already have a month-to-date table below. I want to use below to get year-to-date count against each month by simply adding count for all previous months.

e.g current month-to-date dataset

[image: monthly count]

what I want the result to be is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [row_cumsum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowcumsumfunction) function will do exactly what you're looking for.